# PHP form POST script: the requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php

I'm trying to handle a PHP POST request from an HTML form. You can see in code the HTML form, and the PHP script handling the form POST.

I'm getting the error  `The requested URL /pr/include/Addtion/sum was not found on this server` on POST.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

```html
<html>  
<body>  
<form action = "sum" method="post">  
Enter First Number:  
<input type="number" name="number1" /><br><br>  
Enter Second Number:  
<input type="number" name="number2" /><br><br>  
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">  
</form>  
   
</body>  
</html>
```

> ```
>     <?php  
>     if(isset($_POST['submit']))  
>     {  
>         $number1 = $_POST['number1'];  
>         $number2 = $_POST['number2'];  
>         $sum =  $number1+$number2;     
> echo "The sum of $number1 and $number2 is: ".$sum;   
> }  
> ?>
> ```

Comment: could you please remove the `java` tag because it is not the target language in this question. replace it with `html`

Answer (score 0):

If the php code run on the page itself, just leave the form action empty. or give it name `sum.php` but with extension `.php`.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: Or the full URL of the script handling the POST request

Comment: Just have to avoid give it `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` it will be open to vulnerability `XSS`. just leave it blank or not give it at all, since the deault action  where page go when he click submit is itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly remove the java tag because this question is not related to java,**

> **So ih here change  to   in action tag you haven't mentioned
> *.php***

```
 <html>  
    <body>  
    <form action = "sum.php" method="post">  
    Enter First Number:  
    <input type="number" name="number1" /><br><br>  
    Enter Second Number:  
    <input type="number" name="number2" /><br><br>  
    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">  
    </form>  
       
    </body>  
    </html>
```